# object use own method in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

can object define property to use own method?

litk this

```
obj = {
    prt:function(){console.log("HELLO")}
    prt0:obj.prt()
}
```

I want obj.prt0 -> "HELLO"

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = {
    prt:function(){
        console.log("HELLO")
        return "HELLO";
    },
    prt0: function(){
        this.prt()
    }
}
obj.prt0;    //do nothing, it is only a method
obj.prt0();  //execute method, will print Hello
```

Comment: i don't wanna use another methods. Isn't there any way to use only property? and why property cant approach own methods? even use this.method

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. Because the prt is a function, and it can accept params, you need type () after the function name. If you only want a value, you can use a attribute, like var obj = { prt: 'HELLO'} the use obj.prt, BTW, call a function is simple and clear. why don't you want to use it, you

Answer (score 1):

If you want `obj.prt0` to have the value of `"HELLO"`, then you're going about it the right way - use `this` to make it easier, and make sure you `return` from the function. Also you need to define `prt0` after the object is created:

```js
let obj = {
  prt: function() {
    console.log("HELLO");
    return "HELLO";
  }
};

obj.prt0 = obj.prt();

console.log(obj.prt0);
```

The above does call `obj.prt` to create the value. If you want `prt0` to be a reference to `prt` - so if you call `prt0` it calls `prt`, you can just do this:

```js
let obj = {
  prt: function() {
    console.log("HELLO");
    return "HELLO";
  }
};

obj.prt0 = obj.prt;

console.log(obj.prt0());
```

The above will also call `console.log("HELLO")` twice.